# MassTransit Send And Publish

Tags: .net, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

What are the differences between send and publish methods of Masstransit?
Can you explain with an example?

I use “send” after the process in record update.
I use 'publish' to send mail after a process.

I understand the difference between them. Am i right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of it is extensively described in the documentation.

I suggest reviewing the [Messages](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html#message-names) section, which says, among other things, that commands are *sent* and events are *published*.

The difference between sending and publishing messages is also mentioned in the [Producers](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/producers) section.

> When a message is sent, it is delivered to a specific endpoint using a DestinationAddress. When a message is published, it is not sent to a specific endpoint, but is instead broadcasted to any consumers which have subscribed to the message type. For these two separate behavior, we describe messages sent as commands, and messages published as events.